# Are old green zucchini commonly orange inside?

Tags: zucchini

I was under the impression that zucchini are always supposed to be their regular color inside (pale green or whatever you want to call it). However, twice now I've seen large zucchini that are orange inside (from different people growing them in the same town, on different years). I thought maybe it was cross-pollination the first time, but the person who gave it to me this year wasn't growing anything else but zucchini. So, I'm thinking either they must have the same variety of unique zucchini (which is possible), or zucchini must commonly get like that when it's large (I know it's not always like that).

Anyway, my question is, is this normal? We've grown zucchini lots of times in the past, but only this year and last have I noticed green fruits with orange interiors. The first year, the variety was called Black. This year, I don't know what it is, but it *looks* like the same variety to me.

Here are some pictures of this year's.

[image]

(Although you see me cooking with it here, I should note that the zucchini pictured didn't taste very great, but the one last year that looked about the same tasted awesome.)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are indeed many varieties of zucchini ([*Cucurbita pepo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cucurbita_pepo)) with different fruit shape and skin color. Zucchini are eaten when immature and they typically have green skin and pale green pulp. However when they mature the interior (and often also the skin) tends to become orange and the taste is not very good.

So I believe what you got it's normal when the fruit matures. Again, outcomes can vary a lot for different cultivars.

Comment: And they don't always taste bad, says my experience. :) Last year they were really good.

Comment: I have eaten zucchini as large as shown , they had pale green flesh and were fine . You need to watch them each day, they grow from wimpy grocery store size to BIG in a few days. They do continue to mature after picking so must be cooked as soon as picked.